# how to pass foreign key from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on mvc project.
I have a viewmodel as following

```
public class AddInfoViewModel
{
    public myproject.Models.DomainModels.information information { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<myproject.Models.DomainModels.Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

view :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("company", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", new SelectList(Model.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name"), "select company", htmlAttributes: new  {@class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my action in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(information information)
{
    informationRepository blinformation = new informationRepository();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        double id = blinformation.GetLastIdentity() + 1;
        information.ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        //codes for add to db
        ...
    }
}
```

when I run project the CompanyID that send to create action in controller is zero (0). How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean its `0`? In the POST method when you submit the form? Explain what the issue is.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Your view model is `AddInfoViewModel` but the POST method you have show has nothing to do with that (its parameter is typeof `information`).

Comment: my action get information as arguman. but the field of CompanyID is zero so when it try to add a new record to db there is not any row in companies table with 0 id.there for it throws exception.

Comment: I use AddInfoViewModel in [GET] method to send data into view.

Comment: Your not making any sense. If the model is based on `AddInfoViewModel` - then the POST method needs to be `public ActionResult Create(AddInfoViewModel model)`

Comment: you're right.I made mistake.I change the arguments to     
        public ActionResult Create(AddInfoViewModel model) and my problem solved.thank you for your help.

Comment: @M.baty I dont understand your question. Your action method is receiving an instance of information, you are not receiving the companyid. Do you want the user to select a companyid from a dropdown and then access this value in the action method? And do you also want your action method to receive information?

Comment: @CodingYoshi , I wanted to get companyid in my create action method but my mistake was that create action method recieved information therefor companyid became 0. then I change it and instead of information ,I passed addgisviewmodel as arguments of create action method and myproblem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trust, but you must replace

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", new SelectList(Model.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name")
```

with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID,...)
```